# Parallels between h₂ and t in PIE and Nostratic, what is the explanation?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, semitic-languages

In Afro-Asiatic we have the feminine ending ***-a*** which has the following evolution history:

***-a < -ah<sub>a</sub> < -at < et***

where h<sub>a</sub> is a glottal fricative.

In IE (for instance, in Russian, Greek, Latin) we also have the feminine ending ***-a*** which has the following history (classically):

***-a < ah<sub>a</sub> < eh<sub>a</sub>***

where h<sub>a</sub> is the a-coloring laryngeal.

Can we by analogy suppose that h<sub>a</sub> < t?

This gives a number of analogies between other PIE words:

***h<sub>a</sub>euh<sub>a</sub>os*** <-> ***teutos*** (both "grandfather") (also ***h<sub>a</sub>etos*** is reconstructed for "father" in PIE -> Russian otets)

(compare Proto-Afro-Asiatic ***h<sub>a</sub>abbah<sub>a</sub>*** "father" here)

***h<sub>a</sub>eq<sup>u</sup>-*** <-> ***teq<sup>u</sup>-*** (both "flowing water")

***h<sub>a</sub>ecsom*** <-> ***tecsom*** (both "axe")

***h<sub>a</sub>ecmon*** "stone" <-> ***tecsōn*** "builder"

***h<sub>a</sub>eĝos*** <-> ***teĝos*** (both "leader")

***h<sub>a</sub>ersos*** <-> ***tersos*** (both "dry, e.g., land") (compare also Greek χερσος, "dry land")

How can it be explained?

Comment: @jknappen all h2/t word correspondencies here are taken from PIE.

Comment: You will need to reason why **some** t's became h2's and others didn't.

Comment: How about Sanskrit, which casually replaces final -s with -h? It's just some sort of lenition, IMHO.

Comment: The most probable phonetic value of Indo-European h2 is a voiceless pharyngeal fricative. It is very unlikely that such a sound would develop into, or come from a dental/alveolar stop. On the other hand, h1 is believed to stand for a glottal stop. Shifts of that sort are observed for example in modern English, especially cockney, where [t] is replaced by [ʔ] word internally and finally.

Comment: @czypsu take for instance the word abbot where the final -t came from Aramaic aleph via -s

Comment: [Preust 1999] argues for cases of Egyptian influence spreading into european languages, specifically the feminine Gender; see *Fälle von strukturellem Einfluss des Ägyptischen auf europäische Sprachen*. tl;dr.

Comment: The feminine ending is attested as `/t/` in the oldest stages of Egyptian, so it can't have changed to anything else before Proto-Afro-Asiatic broke up. (We only see this `/t/` disappearing from Egyptian around the mid-second-millennium BCE, long after PAA times.)

Comment: Also, re your latest edit—why do you say the feminine ending became a pharyngeal fricative? I can't think of any AA language that has `/ʕ/` (ayin) for its feminine marker.

Comment: @Draconis In Hebrew it is hey so I guessed so

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica after some analysis it seems the most paired words with t are considered pre-PIE substrate words. If so, they can be borrowings from a non-PIE but related language. This hints that in the common ancestor of PIE and that language these words probably had aspirated t in that position (which PIE lacks unlike aspirated d). In PIE it bacame h2 while in that sister language it became plain t.

Comment: @Anixx Hebrew he is a glottal fricative `/h/`, not pharyngeal. Biblical Hebrew had a separate phoneme `/ʕ/` written with a different letter (and also a voiceless `/ħ/` written with a different letter), which afaik is never used to write the feminine ending.

Comment: @Draconis fixed...

Answer (score 6):

Let’s just take the beginning:

> In Afro-Asiatic we have the feminine ending -a which has the following
>   evolution history:
>
> -a < -ah<sub>a</sub> < -at < et

What does -ah<sub>a</sub> mean in an AA context? There are actually lots of real-life laryngeals in Semitic. Which one is h<sub>a</sub>? Where does “et” come from? Then you write:

> where h<sub>a</sub> is aleph

Aleph is the first letter of the alphabet. Are we talking about phonology or about spelling? Actually, the pausal form of the feminine singular nouns (which is what you are talking about) is spelt with final aleph in Eastern Aramaic, but with he in Western Aramaic, Hebrew and Arabic. Which one do you think is more original? And why is this orthographic question at all relevant?